# Dynamic Reconfigure in Hydro- gencfg()

Tags: ros-hydro, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody!

While trying to create a dynamic reconfigure node in ROS Hydro, I followed this tutorial:
wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode

I tried to catkin_make my package and I get various errors, mainly because it seems to be an outdated version and the packages of dynamic_reconfigure still have commands like rosbuild which I cannot compile (e.g. I include the following lines in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
# add dynamic reconfigure api
include(/opt/ros/hydro/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()
```

and catkin_make gives me the following errors:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:23 

(add_dependencies):
  add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target:
  rospack_genmsg_libexe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  imagepub/CMakeLists.txt:195 (include)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:31 (rosbuild_find_ros_package):
  Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_find_ros_package".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  imagepub/CMakeLists.txt:195 (include)
```

Is there a newer tutorial I can look at?
Or if not, are there new packages/cmake files I should use?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98596/dynamic-reconfigure-in-hydro--gencfg()/) by [sotirios](https://answers.ros.org/users/8526/sotirios/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dont use that code, you have to migrate it to catkin. It has a few steps, from

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

> dynamic_reconfigure
>
> For each .cfg file:
>
> Remove "import roslib;roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)".
> Change "from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *" to "from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *"
> In CMakeLists.txt, add the following before the call to catkin_package():
>
> generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/DynFile1.cfg cfg/DynFile2.cfg ...)

> ## make sure configure headers are built before any node using them
>
> add_dependencies(example_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
> For more details see: the catkin dynamic reconfigure how-to and dynamic_reconfigure >tutorial

---

Originally posted by [mts](https://answers.ros.org/users/8736/mts/) with karma: 46 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2013-11-20**:
Hello,

I am also having a problem. I get an error such that:

add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target: fruit_detection

for the line in CMakeList ---> add_dependencies(fruit_detection ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

Do you have any idea what problem is here ?

**Comment by [sotirios](https://answers.ros.org/users/8526/sotirios/) on 2013-11-20**:
I solved my problem, but never got a problem with the dependencies. Did you remember to have a definition like this in CMakeList before adding dependencies (the add_dependencies must follow the addition)?
add_executable(fruit_detection src/fruit_detection.cpp)

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2013-11-22**:
Thanks very much ! That helped !

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-06-27**:
The instructions provided by the migration guide are patently wrong because they say I have to add add_dependencies **before** calling catkin_package(), which is much before adding the executable. If I put add_dependecies just after add_executable It complains that the *.h file generated from the cfg is missing, if I put add_dependencies just before catkin_package() it complains that the target is non-existent. What should I do???

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-06-28**:
I updated the migration guide (http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild?action=diff&rev1=101&rev2=102). Only the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options()" line must be invoked before "catkin_package()" - the "add_dependencies()" line must be places after you defined the corresponding target.

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-06-30**:
OK for me now it works (there was a missing include). Check also the link after "For more details see:" because for me it's broken.